# Обращение из вложенного блока WITH к внешнему WITH

Tags: vb.net

```
  With New Object() {1, 2}
        Dim debug_1 As Object = .ElementAt(0) ;Тут всё понятно - получаем 1 из object
        With New Object() {3, 4}
            Dim debug_2 As Object = .ElementAt(0) ;Тут получаем 3
            ;Вот тут вопрос возникает - как обратится к внешнему блоку WITH, что бы получить из него например 2?
        End With
  End With
```

Comment: В `c#` нет никакого `with`

Comment: Да, в C# есть using

Comment: using и vb есть, но это другая история

Answer (score 0):

Придумал решение ;)

```
With New Object() {1, 2}    
    With New Object() {3, 4}.Concat(.ToArray)
         Dim debug_0 As Object = .ToArray(3)  ;Так и получаем 2
    End With
End With
```